# How to fire two functions, one while page reloading/refreshing another ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the controller.

```
$scope.userhold_payment = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/ngaffiliate/api/payment/change_hold_payment_status')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('I called');
            $scope.userhold = response.data;
            // console.log($scope.userhold.is_hold_payment);
        });
};
$scope.check_status = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/ngaffiliate/api/payment/check_payment_status')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('I called now')
            $scope.checkstatus = response.data;
            console.log(response);
            console.log($scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment);
        });
}
```

Here is the main.html

```
<div ng-init="check_status()">
    <button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment()" class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Hold Payment</button>
</div>
```

Upon reloading, I want the function checkstatus() to get initialised and upon-clicking ng-click, userhold_payment(). How do I do this? I used $scope before using ng-init but it fired the userhold_payment() everytime it reloaded, which I do not want.

Many thanks!

Comment: it would be better if you can create a demo/fiddle to replicate the problem. Will be able to help better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$scope.userhold_payment = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/ngaffiliate/api/payment/change_hold_payment_status')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('I called');
            $scope.userhold = response.data;
            // console.log($scope.userhold.is_hold_payment);
        });
};

//this will call when ever your controller reinstance
($scope.check_status = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/ngaffiliate/api/payment/check_payment_status')
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('I called now')
            $scope.checkstatus = response.data;
            console.log(response);
            console.log($scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment);
        });
})();
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="userhold_payment()" class="btn-success btn-lg hold_payment_html" style="margin-top:7px; font-size:16px">Hold Payment</button>
</div>
```

It is better to use controller rather going for [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: Thanks! How do I change the button name on clicking? I tried ng-show and ng-if, but I needed ng-init for that. Thanks again! You saved me, literally.

Comment: You have to use ng-init in proper way once go through the docs @Dinesh Gupta

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using window onload event , look at snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);

app.controller("demoCtrl",function($scope,$window){

  $window.onload = function(){
   alert("load event");
  }
  $scope.clickFunction =function(){
    alert("ng-click event");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <div>
   <button ng-click="clickFunction()">click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A function call initializing the data should probably take place within the controller. If you bring in a module called [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) you can easily make data persist within page refresh with minimal work.

```
$scope.check_status=function(){
   $http.get('http://localhost/ngaffiliate/api/payment/check_payment_status')
      .then(function(response){
          console.log('I called now')
          $localStorage.checkstatus = $scope.checkstatus = response.data;
          console.log(response);
          console.log($scope.checkstatus.is_hold_payment);
        });
}
if ($localStorage.checkstatus){
    $scope.checkstatus = $localStorage.checkstatus;
}
else{
    $scope.check_status();
}
```